# Flutter web UI does not zoom in properly

Tags: flutter-web

I just starting using flutter web since it's stable release. One thing I observed about this is the UI is not zoomed in like other web app.

Below is the default starter app which appears on creating a new flutter project. I've just changed the body color of Scaffold to notice the issue properly.

[image]

It's good the it's zoom is not responsive to scroll wheel of a mouse but when I use the touchpad of my laptop to zoom in, it responds to it. The result of zoom is a bit unexpected.

Below is the result.

[image]

In this case I kept my cursor to the center of screen and zoomed it. Keeping the cursor anywhere leads to almost same kind of UI.

Any workaround for it? Or maybe if I can disable this pinch zoom feature ?

Comment: I'm facing same issue with latest v2.8 Did you solve it..